# how to add marker on screen touch with openlayers

Tags: javascript, touch, openlayers

i'm using sencha touch and openlayers for a mobile app !
i want to add a marker when i touch the map like "onLongPress" with android !
what  m searching for is a similar code but who support the touch screen .

```
 map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
  //var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
  var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
  var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
  var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
  var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('images/mark.png', size, offset);   
  var markerslayer = map.getLayer('Markers');
  markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon));

 });
```

thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure if your mobile device translates these long clicks in some normal 'click'-event. Have you tried the new touch control? http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/TouchNavigation-js.html and this example: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-sencha.html